# How to share topics between two protocols in mosquitto

Tags: websocket, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I am using mosquitto mqtt both with MQTT protocol and MQTT over websockets protocol. Some client use mqtt protocol and some uses websocket protocol due to their limitations. MQTT port is 1883 and websocket port is 8083. The problem is that I want to share all the topics on both port i.e. on websocket and MQTT. What type of configurations i should do in my MQTT broker or any other solution?

In other words I want to listen to all topics on websocket(port 8083) which are published on mqtt(port 1883) on same broker and vise versa.

**mosquitto.conf** file is following

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd

listener 8083 127.0.0.1
protocol websockets
```

Comment: That config file only has a websocket listener, where is the native MQTT listener?

Comment: by default MQTT port is 1883 and its working on it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to change anything.

There is only one topic space shared across all listeners/protocols with mosquitto.

The following mosquitto.conf works:

```
port 1883

listener 8083
protocol websockets
```

Used with the following nodejs app to test websockets:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('ws://localhost:8083')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('#')
  client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log("%s - %s", topic, message.toString())
})
```

and native MQTT messages injected with `mosquitto_pub -t "foo" -m "bar"` and monitored with `mosquitto_sub -v -t '#'`

Whole thing running mosquitto v1.4.14 (from the mosquitto ppa) on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Thanks for your response. :) I didn't got your point. Actually I want to listen to all topics on websocket(port 8803) which are published on mqtt(port 1883) on same broker.

Comment: yes, that's what I said. It doesn't matter which protocol the client is connected with, it can publish and see all topics from all clients

Comment: but when I publish any thing to a topic on port 1883(i.e. mqtt connection) I don't receive anything on port 8803 (i.e. on ws connection). even I have subscribed to all topics

Comment: Edit the question to include your mosquitto.conf file so we can see what you've setup.

Comment: done! there is noting special to share the topic between these two protocols, this is what i am looking for.. :(

Comment: Unless you are running 2 separate instances of mosquitto (one for each protocol) it should just work.

Comment: both ports 1883 and 8083 are working but both are working independently. i.e. topics which are published/subscribed on 1883 are working individually and topics which are published/subscribed on 8803 are working individually.